# How to access items in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have this code :

```
List<MyTable> list = db.MyTable.ToList();
list = list.FindAll(x => x.ID == entry.IDClient);
```

The only way I found to access the values returned was using a foreach :

```
foreach (var myList in list)
{
    entry.Address = myList.Address ;
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Use `list[0]` to access the first item, `list[1]` for the second, and so on. See [MSDN: `List<T>.Item` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And what problem do you have with using a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Some kind of associative index ? Like `list=>Adress` ? Or can only use numbers ?

Comment: @AlanoTeles You can use `list[0].Address` to get the `Address` property of the first item.

Comment: @Servy, it's because I find a little strange to use a foreach to only one line. I visualized lists like arrays and questioned if was possible to access directly an element when you have a array with just one line. I'm still learning C#...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List<T>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) instead of `FindAll`.  This will return a single element.

```
var listItem = list.Find(x => x.ID == entry.IDClient);
entry.Address = listItem.Address;
```

Comment: why do you think he needs a single element ?

Comment: @Selman22 Because of the assignment he's doing ;)  He's assigning to a single `entity` ...

Comment: @Selman22 Look at the code - he's trying to find the element in MyTable that matches `entity.IDClient` and then copy across the address - seems like single element is the problem here.

Comment: Ok guys, what solved the problem was a change in tha way I was creating the list, using part of the solution @ReedCopsey. And to directly access the value without the need of a `foreach`, the tip of @p.s.w.g solved.  
`List<MyTable> list = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == entry.IDClient).ToList(); `     
`entry.Address= list[0].Address;`
*Sorry by bad formatting, but my spaces are not being converted for blocks of code or line breaks. Tks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `foreach` loop like you said:

```
foreach(var I in list)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

or you can call the individual item inside the list if you know what position the item you want is.

```
list[0]
```

this will give you the first item, and so on...

you can also use a for loop to iterate through the list:

```
for(int I = 0; I < list.lenght; I++)
{
    list[I]
}
```